# How can I hide the style code from the screen?

Tags: php, html, css

The CSS code for the navbar appears at the top of the page. How can I hide it? I use internal CSS.

Here's how it looks in the browser:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="layout/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="layout/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
  <style>      
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body{
  display: inline;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}
nav .logo{
  color: white;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
nav{
  height: 70px;
  background: #063247;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #063247;
  transition: .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active{
  color: #23dbdb;
}
nav ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  border-top: 3px solid #23dbdb;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: .3s linear;
}
nav ul ul li{
  width: 150px;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #042331;
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul ul li a{
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul ul ul{
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  left: 150px;
}
nav ul ul li a i{
  margin-left: 45px;
}
section{
  background: url(bg.jpeg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>    
</head>

<body>    
<nav>
         <label class="logo">Clothes Store</label>
         <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="home.php">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
            <li>
               <a href="viewProducts.php">الفئات
               <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
               </a>
             </li>
            <li><a href="addProduct.php">إضافة منتجات</a>
          </li>
            
            <li><a href="">السلة</a></li>
            <li><a href="">التواصل</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="logOut.php">تسجيل الخروج</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>  

</body>
</html>
```

On all pages, this code appears at the top of the page.
What is the wrong in the code?
At first it doesn't appear, but then suddenly comes:
.....................................................

Comment: Please share your code, we can't troubleshoot images :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code in the image does not appear to be enclosed in <style> ... css code ... </style>

Comment: I put the code.

Comment: Have you tested the above code after inserting the `<style>...</style>`? Because now the error is no longer reproducible. Also defining `body { display: inline }` is a  **VERY BAD** idea. If you must, create an 'inline' `<div class="wrapper">...</div>` with all your html.

Comment: To future readers: the code as it is now in the question doesn't reproduce the problem, as it is the solution code.